# Query to display rows from a table related to certain number of days in Oracle

Tags: oracle, date

I'm a newbie to DB and I've a question regarding displaying contents from a table based on date.

How can I search for all the entities from **`EMPLOYEE`** table which matches certain value in **`EmpPayScaleID`** and +/- 3 days of **`EmpPayDate`**

For example,
I need to print all the values form **`EMPLOYEE`** table where **`EmpPayScaleId`** is **`1001`** and **`EmpPayDate`** should be +/- 3 days from 01-AUG-17 **(should show records from 29-JUL-17 to 04-SEP-17)**

I tried this:

```
SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEE
              WHERE EmpPayScaleId = 1001
              AND EmpPayDate in ADD_MONTHS(01-Aug-17, -3, dd-mm-yy)  
              AND EmpPayDate in ADD_MONTHS(01-Aug-17, 3, dd-mm-yy);
```

**Correction:**

```
SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEE
              WHERE EmpPayScaleId = 1001
              AND EmpPayDate in ADD_MONTHS(01-Aug-17, -3, 'DD-MON-YY')  
              AND EmpPayDate in ADD_MONTHS(01-Aug-17, 3, 'DD-MON-YY');
```

This shows nothing.  Where was my mistake?
Is this a correct query?

**Edit:**
It shows invalid number of arguments when I use `ADD_MONTHS(01-AUG-17, 3, 'DD-MON-YY')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The date in your query has been specified incorrectly.
The following where clause is enough:

```
...
WHERE EmpPayScaleId = 1001
          AND to_date('01-Aug-17','DD-MON-YY') between EmpPayDate-3 
                                                   and EmpPayDate+3;
```

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks! :D